# Convert the extracted digit with regex into int

Tags: python, regex

I have this piece of code

```py
re.sub(r"(\d)?\((\w*)\)", r"\2" * int(r"\1") ,st)
```

I'm trying to repeat the word found in the second capturing group by the number in the first capturing group, if any.

Even if it captures a digit I get this error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\\1'`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use a callable as the replacement argument to be able to manipulate the backreference data.

Comment: I tried and I always get some errors. I can't figure out the syntax..

Comment: Then please show what you have tried. What you showed is a wrong use of backreferences in the replacement pattern.

Comment: ok I found it `re.sub(r"(\d)?\((\w*)\)", lambda x: x.group(2) * int(x.group(1)) ,st)`